# MS SQL Server 2016 using JSON methods to get values

Tags: json, sql-server

It is probably something stupid what I did not see, but I can't manage to get `JSON_VALUE` or `JSON_QUERY` to work as I expect how it should work:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{"1031":"test-de","1033":"test-en","1036":"test-fr"}'

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
```

returns correct 3 rows.

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{"1031":"test-de","1033":"test-en","1036":"test-fr"}'
SELECT ISJSON(@json) is_json
  , JSON_VALUE(@json, '$') label
  , JSON_QUERY(@json, '$') label2
```

returns 1 row, but `label` is `NULL` and `label2` shows the whole string. OK, but:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{"1031":"test-de","1033":"test-en","1036":"test-fr"}'
SELECT ISJSON(@json) is_json
  , JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.1031') label
  , JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.1033') label2
```

returns 0 rows.

**EDIT**

I did expect to get results like this:

```
is_json, label, label2
1, test-de, test-en
```

Comment: What resultset *are* you after then?

Comment: @Larnu updated question to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your Key starts with a number, you need to quote it. I *think* what you're after is:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{"1031":"test-de","1033":"test-en","1036":"test-fr"}'

SELECT ISJSON(@json) AS is_json,
       JSON_VALUE(@json, '$."1031"') AS label,
       JSON_VALUE(@json, '$."1033"') AS label2;
```

Alternatively you could use a `WITH`:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{"1031":"test-de","1033":"test-en","1036":"test-fr"}'

SELECT ISJSON(@json) is_json,
       J.label1,
       J.label2
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
     WITH (label1 varchar(7) '$."1031"',
           label2 varchar(7) '$."1033"') J;
```